# How to display google-cloud-bigquery version using SQL?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there some command to display Google-BigQuery version using SQL.

For example, to show version for MS SQL Server, we would use `SELECT @@VERSION`

Comment: Query syntax for bigquery docs: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you have any command to display Google-BigQuery version using SQL

However, To get the latest product updates delivered to you, go to [Bigquery Latest Product Update](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes)

Answer (score 1):

Big Query uses two dialects.

**Big Query SQL [Legacy SQL]** - This was an internal version of SQL for querying Big Query

**Standard SQL** - This dialect compiles using [SQL 2011 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2011). It is a generally and more publically used version of SQL.

For more details between the two dialects, refer [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql).